# What is the best Java-based Mailing List application allowing opt-in/opt-out

Tags: java, email, open-source, rss, subscription

I'm looking for a java-based (preferable) mailing list application that allows users to opt-in/opt-out of mailing lists.  Open-source is preferable but not mandatory.

This product would be used to send email notifications to subscribed people when certain events happen in another application - i.e.  when a new record is saved and approved with certain attributes, a message is sent to one or more mailing lists.

It should be able to handle multiple mailing lists and must have an interface for sending new messages programatically without the need to use it's web/gui interface.

A last resort would be to develop our own application to perform this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a hosted service for email marketing. Sure, you may find just the right software for the job. The main issue is deliverability. A mailing service increases the chances of your mail reaching the destination. It also provides very useful reports of how many opened and who clicked what. IMHO, the price of those services is very much justified.

I'm using [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) and I'm happy with their service. They have an easy to use API, so you can control your campaigns programatically. I'm invoking it from Java and I'm in the process of packing my code to post it online.

Comment: i will need to do the same thing, i just stumbled to your post and was wondering if you already posted it online? Would be of much help!

Comment: Yes, in the official MailChimp api site. http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/downloads/#java

Comment: great, thanx!if i have some question, can i be free to ask?

Comment: There's a Google group called mailchimp-api-discuss which is the best place to ask questions regarding the MC API. I don't hang out there much, though. If you wanna ask me, you can post your question here and ping me (e.g. send me a tweet to @zvikico).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to handle opt-in and opt-out operations in a web application, store addresses per "list" in whatever database you prefer and just use the JavaMail API to handle the actual email functionality. It's trivial, much easier to integrate into an existing app, and you'll be much happier later on when you have to maintain this system.